# How in PostgreSQL to update an attribute inside a column with a JSONB and also keeping the data already inside

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a situation where in a table called *tokens* I have a column called *data*
The data columns consist of something like this as a `'{}'::jsonb`

```
{"recipientId": "xxxxxxxx"}
```

My goal is to have as follow to update old data to new DB design and requirements

```
{"recipientIds": ["xxxxxxxx"]}
```

The reason is that the naming was changed and the value will be an array of recipients.

I don't know how to achieve this

- change `recipientId`to `recipientIds`
- change the value format to an array but to not loose the data
- Also this need to be done only where I have a `type in ('INVITE_ECONSENT_SIGNATURE', 'INVITE_ECONSENT_RECIPIENT')`

The table looks as follow is a simple table which contains few columns.
The data is the only one as `'{}'::jsonb`.

| id | type | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | type1 | data1 |
| 2 | type2 | data1 |

As an edit what I tried to do and partially solved my problem but cannot understand how to se the value to be [value]

```
update
    "token"
set
    "data" = data - 'recipientId' || jsonb_build_object('recipientIds', data->'recipientId')
where
    "type" in ('INVITE_ECONSENT_RECIPIENT')
```

I can have now a `recipientids: value` but need to have `recipientids: [value]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you need to pass an array as the second parameter of the `jsonb_build_object()` function:

```
(data - 'recipientId')||jsonb_build_object(
                            'recipientIds', 
                            jsonb_build_array(data -> 'recipientId')
                        )
```